# java regex who have condition

Tags: java, regex

i have a condition like this

```
[msg "Invalid HTTP Request Line"] [data "CONNECT www.alipay.com:443 HTTP/1.1"] [severity "WARNING"]
```

and I want to match `invalid HTTP Request Line`

I try with this

```
\]\s\[msg\s\"(.+)\"\]\s((\[data)|(\[severity))
```

with that regex the pattern i have until `[saverity`

Comment: You want to match it according to what rules? If you just want to match that string, then the regex is `"Invalid HTTP Request Line"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the starting `\]\s` pattern and also you need to change `(.+)`  to `(.+?)` or `([^\"]+)` because `.+` is greedy by default. It matches all the characters greedily upto the double quotes which exists before `severity`.

```
\[msg\s\"([^\"]+)\"\]\s(?:\[data|\[severity)
```

And get the string you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eG6qA4/2)

```
String s = "[msg \"Invalid HTTP Request Line\"] [data \"CONNECT www.alipay.com:443 HTTP/1.1\"] [severity \"WARNING\"]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[msg\\s\"([^\"]+)\"\\]\\s\\[(?:data|severity)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
Invalid HTTP Request Line
```